# Create a flag with a CASE statement pulling on multiple tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, case

Running SQL Server Management Studio v18.1.

I have a query that returns 153 patient encounter records meeting certain procedure code and date criteria. I have another query that returns medications associated with those patients (thousands of rows). I'd like to combine those queries in a way that flags each of the 153 patient encounters as 1 if certain medications are associated with the patient and 0 otherwise. My current attempt is to use a CASE WHEN statement, but it runs for a long time and returns rows that don't meet my procedure date and type criteria. I assume I'm doing something wrong with the various joins, or maybe that CASE WHEN is not the right solution. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is the query that returns 153 patient encounters:

```
SELECT TOP(1000) pe.PatientEncounterID
      ,pt.MRN
      ,pe.HospitalAccountID
      ,hacpt.CPT
      ,hacpt.CPTDSC
      ,hacpt.ProcedurePerformDT
      ,pe.EncounterTypeDSC
      ,pe.AppointmentStatusDSC
      ,pe.VisitTypeID
      ,pe.VisitTypeDSC
      ,hacpt.PerformingProviderID
      ,prv.ProviderNM
      ,prv.PrimarySpecialtyDSC
      ,pe.PatientDetailTypeDSC
 FROM EDW.Encounter.PatientEncounter pe
 JOIN EDW.Billing.HospitalAccountCPT hacpt ON hacpt.HospitalAccountID = pe.HospitalAccountID
 JOIN EDW.Provider.Provider prv ON prv.ProviderID = pe.VisitProviderID
 JOIN EDW.Patient.Patient pt ON pt.PatientID = pe.PatientID
 WHERE 
  hacpt.ProcedurePerformDT > '2023-05-01'
  AND pe.AppointmentStatusID = 2
  AND hacpt.CPT IN ('00731', '00732', '00740', '00810', '00811',
'00813', '0397T', '3130F', '43254', '43266', '43273', '44360', '44361',
'44370', '44383', '44384', '44397', '44402', '44403', '45347', '45349',
'45387', '45389', '45390', '47550', '47552', '47553', '47554', '76975',
'9124', 'C9779')
AND prv.ProviderID IN ('30638', '35018', '08707', '08700', '29288', '08711', '32763', '33093', '28411', '28326')
```

Here is my medication list query:

```
SELECT    omed.PatientEncounterID
      ,omed.StartDT
      ,omed.EndDT
      ,omed.DiscontinueDTS
      ,emed.EpicMedicationID
      ,emed.GenericProductID
      ,emed.MedicationNM
      ,emed.PharmaceuticalClassCD
      ,emed.PharmaceuticalClassDSC
      ,emed.PharmaceuticalSubclassCD
      ,emed.PharmaceuticalSubclassDSC
      ,emed.GrouperMedicationID
      ,CASE WHEN emed.ProductTypeID = 2 THEN 'OTC' ELSE 'Prescription' END AS MedType
    FROM Reference.EpicMedication emed
    LEFT JOIN Orders.OrderMedication omed ON omed.EpicMedicationID = emed.EpicMedicationID
    WHERE omed.EndDT > GETDATE()
        AND (omed.DiscontinueDTS IS NULL OR omed.DiscontinueDTS > GETDATE())
        AND (
        (omed.OrderStatusDSC IS NULL) OR omed.OrderStatusDSC NOT IN ('Canceled') )
        AND (GenericNM LIKE '%apixaban%'
        OR GenericNM LIKE '%Aspirin%'
        OR GenericNM LIKE '%Cilostazol%'
        OR GenericNM LIKE '%Clopidogrel%'
        OR GenericNM LIKE '%Dapigatran%'
        OR GenericNM LIKE '%Edoxaban%'
        OR GenericNM LIKE '%Prasugrel%'
        OR GenericNM LIKE '%Ticlopidine%'
        OR GenericNM LIKE '%Rivaroxaban%'
        OR GenericNM LIKE '%Warfarin%')
    GROUP BY omed.PatientEncounterID
      ,omed.StartDT
      ,omed.EndDT
      ,omed.DiscontinueDTS
      ,emed.EpicMedicationID
      ,emed.GenericProductID
      ,emed.MedicationNM
      ,emed.PharmaceuticalClassCD
      ,emed.PharmaceuticalClassDSC
      ,emed.PharmaceuticalSubclassCD
      ,emed.PharmaceuticalSubclassDSC
      ,emed.GrouperMedicationID
      ,CASE WHEN emed.ProductTypeID = 2 THEN 'OTC' ELSE 'Prescription' END
```

Here is my attempt at combining the two. Again, what I want/expect is to return 153 rows as with my first query but with an added column for Med_Flg but I am getting rows that don't match my hacpt.ProcedurePerformDT > '2023-05-01' or hacpt.CPT IN criteria.

```
SELECT TOP(1000) pe.PatientEncounterID
      ,pt.MRN
      ,pe.HospitalAccountID
      ,hacpt.CPT
      ,hacpt.CPTDSC
      ,hacpt.ProcedurePerformDT
      ,pe.EncounterTypeDSC
      ,pe.AppointmentStatusDSC
      ,pe.VisitTypeID
      ,pe.VisitTypeDSC
      ,hacpt.PerformingProviderID
      ,prv.ProviderNM
      ,prv.PrimarySpecialtyDSC
      ,pe.PatientDetailTypeDSC
      ,CASE WHEN (emed.GenericNM LIKE '%apixaban%'
        OR emed.GenericNM LIKE '%Aspirin%'
        OR emed.GenericNM LIKE '%Cilostazol%'
        OR emed.GenericNM LIKE '%Clopidogrel%'
        OR emed.GenericNM LIKE '%Dapigatran%'
        OR emed.GenericNM LIKE '%Edoxaban%'
        OR emed.GenericNM LIKE '%Prasugrel%'
        OR emed.GenericNM LIKE '%Ticlopidine%'
        OR emed.GenericNM LIKE '%Rivaroxaban%'
        OR emed.GenericNM LIKE '%Warfarin%'
        ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS "Med_Flg"
 FROM EDW.Encounter.PatientEncounter pe
 JOIN EDW.Billing.HospitalAccountCPT hacpt ON hacpt.HospitalAccountID = pe.HospitalAccountID
 JOIN EDW.Provider.Provider prv ON prv.ProviderID = pe.VisitProviderID
 JOIN EDW.Patient.Patient pt ON pt.PatientID = pe.PatientID
    LEFT JOIN Reference.EpicMedication emed
    LEFT JOIN Orders.OrderMedication omed ON omed.EpicMedicationID = emed.EpicMedicationID ON pe.PatientEncounterID = omed.PatientEncounterID
 WHERE 
  hacpt.ProcedurePerformDT > '2023-05-01'
  AND AppointmentStatusID = 2
  AND CPT IN ('00731', '00732', '00740', '00810', '00811',
'00813', '0397T', '3130F', '43254', '43266', '43273', '44360', '44361',
'44370', '44383', '44384', '44397', '44402', '44403', '45347', '45349',
'45387', '45389', '45390', '47550', '47552', '47553', '47554', '76975',
'9124', 'C9779')
AND prv.ProviderID IN ('30638', '35018', '08707', '08700', '29288', '08711', '32763', '33093', '28411', '28326')
AND (omed.OrderStatusDSC IS NULL ) 
  OR (omed.OrderStatusDSC NOT IN ('Canceled')
  )
  AND omed.EndDT > GETDATE()
GROUP BY pe.PatientEncounterID
      ,pt.MRN
      ,prv.ProviderNM
      ,hacpt.ProcedurePerformDT
      ,hacpt.CPT
      ,pe.HospitalAccountID
      ,hacpt.CPTDSC
      ,pe.EncounterTypeDSC
      ,pe.AppointmentStatusDSC
      ,pe.VisitTypeID
      ,pe.VisitTypeDSC
      ,hacpt.PerformingProviderID
      ,prv.PrimarySpecialtyDSC
      ,pe.PatientDetailTypeDSC
      ,CASE WHEN (GenericNM LIKE '%apixaban%'
        OR GenericNM LIKE '%Aspirin%'
        OR GenericNM LIKE '%Cilostazol%'
        OR GenericNM LIKE '%Clopidogrel%'
        OR GenericNM LIKE '%Dapigatran%'
        OR GenericNM LIKE '%Edoxaban%'
        OR GenericNM LIKE '%Prasugrel%'
        OR GenericNM LIKE '%Ticlopidine%'
        OR GenericNM LIKE '%Rivaroxaban%'
        OR GenericNM LIKE '%Warfarin%'
        ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! With a proper [mcve] you will get better answers, faster!

Comment: The version of SSMS is not super important here, the version of SQL Server is.

Comment: Emphasis on *minimal* we don't need your actual query just a cut down one the demonstrates the issue. Also one case is an expression not a statement.

Comment: Telling us you use Management Studio is like telling us the car you drive is a Sony, because that's the brand you see on the dashboard radio. Fine for some, alarming from your mechanic.

Comment: On a more-productive note, at a high level you could always combine those queries by JOINing them as subqueries, and then use conditional aggregation or case expressions to project the desired new column. This will cause duplicate rows when more than one medication matches. You _could_ handle this with a long GROUP BY clause, but a row_number() strategy may be more effective instead.

Comment: @Chris Albert, how do I determine the version of SQL server?

Comment: @Dale K, I'm afraid I'm not fluent enough in SQL to know what would be the minimum that would show the problem but I will work on that moving forward.

Comment: `select @@version;` will give you SQL Server version.

Comment: So, playing around some more I think I solved the problem with HAVING for my CPT code list and provider list. I'll need to do some validation but moving those returns 153 rows.

Comment: Thanks, jarlh. That returns Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU13) (KB5005679) - 15.0.4178.1 (X64)

Comment: Minimal would mean you remove most of the columns, because whether you show 20 or 2 doesn't change the logic. You could also remove most of the joins I would guess. But also you should be providing us with sample data and desired results. All in all, creating such a minimal example will not only help you understand the problem better, understand SQL better, and frequently people solve their own issue when creating the minimsl example because they realise what was actually going on.

Answer (score 0):

The precedence of the `OR` operator relative to `AND` often surprises and catches people. We have this except in the code:

```
AND (omed.OrderStatusDSC IS NULL ) 
  OR (omed.OrderStatusDSC NOT IN ('Canceled')
  )
```

And it should probably look like this instead:

```
AND (omed.OrderStatusDSC IS NULL  
  OR omed.OrderStatusDSC NOT IN ('Canceled')
  )
```

Which I might write instead as:

```
coalesce(omed.OrderStatusDSC, '') <> 'Canceled'
```

Otherwise, there's more code here than I have time to review.

Separately, it looks like joining the additional tables from the second query to add the medications means each of the original 153 patient rows could potentially occur many times in the results (once for each matched medication), and the strategy to resolve this was to group by the desired output columns.

This strategy can work, but there are also alternatives. One common option is to instead use `row_number() over` with will-chosen partitions and ordering so we can only includes results where the row_number() is 1. This can be just as effective, run faster, and need less code.

Another option is using an `APPLY` operation instead of a JOIN for the tables from the additional query, where the APPLY is limited to one row.

But the *best* option is probably to tune the additional medication query more before combining it with the patient query in the first place, to reduce it down to a single column that only has the key from the first query. Then LEFT JOIN with *that* instead, so NULL is 0 and anything else is 1.

Comment: And in SQL Server 2022 you can do `omed.OrderStatusDSC is distinct from 'Canceled'`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be way off the mark as not all you column names are prefixed with the alias so I'm guessing a bit here, also this might not perform great but I'm trying to simplify the query.

I would create a view that contains a simple distinct list of patients that match the medication criteria. For example

```
CREATE VIEW PatientsOnSpecificMeds AS
SELECT DISTINCT pe.PatientID
FROM Reference.EpicMedication emed
    JOIN Orders.OrderMedication omed ON omed.EpicMedicationID = emed.EpicMedicationID 
    JOIN EDW.Patient.Patient pt ON pt.PatientID = pe.PatientID
    WHERE omed.OrderStatusDSC IS NULL
        OR omed.OrderStatusDSC NOT IN ('Canceled')
        AND omed.EndDT > GETDATE()
        AND emed.GenericNM LIKE '%apixaban%' OR
            emed.GenericNM LIKE '%Aspirin%' OR
            emed.GenericNM LIKE '%Cilostazol%' OR
            emed.GenericNM LIKE '%Clopidogrel%' OR
            emed.GenericNM LIKE '%Dapigatran%' OR
            emed.GenericNM LIKE '%Edoxaban%' OR
            emed.GenericNM LIKE '%Prasugrel%' OR
            emed.GenericNM LIKE '%Ticlopidine%' OR
            emed.GenericNM LIKE '%Rivaroxaban%' OR
            emed.GenericNM LIKE '%Warfarin%'
```

Now in your main query you don't need either of the `CASE`s you can simply left join to the view above using `PatientID` from the `EDW.Patient.Patient` table. If the PatientID from the view is null then you "flag" will be 0

e.g. (not using aliases as it's not a complete bit of code)

```
IIF(PatientsOnSpecificMeds.PatientID ISNULL, 0,1) AS Med_flg
```

or if using an old version of SQL Server

```
CASE WHEN PatientsOnSpecificMeds.PatientID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Med_Flg
```

Answer (score 0):

roughly speaking I've taken your first query and added the second query as a outer join table ( removing the unneeded projected cols ) where if the row exists then the med_flg is 1 otherwise 0 - HTH

```
SELECT TOP(1000) pe.PatientEncounterID
  ,pt.MRN
  ,pe.HospitalAccountID
  ,hacpt.CPT
  ,hacpt.CPTDSC
  ,hacpt.ProcedurePerformDT
  ,pe.EncounterTypeDSC
  ,pe.AppointmentStatusDSC
  ,pe.VisitTypeID
  ,pe.VisitTypeDSC
  ,hacpt.PerformingProviderID
  ,prv.ProviderNM
  ,prv.PrimarySpecialtyDSC
  ,pe.PatientDetailTypeDSC
  ,case when meds.patientEncounterID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS "Med_Flg"
   FROM EDW.Encounter.PatientEncounter pe
   JOIN EDW.Billing.HospitalAccountCPT hacpt ON hacpt.HospitalAccountID 
= pe.HospitalAccountID
   JOIN EDW.Provider.Provider prv ON prv.ProviderID = pe.VisitProviderID
   JOIN EDW.Patient.Patient pt ON pt.PatientID = pe.PatientID
   left join (select omed.PatientEncounterID FROM 
Reference.EpicMedication emed
        LEFT JOIN Orders.OrderMedication omed ON omed.EpicMedicationID = 
emed.EpicMedicationID
        WHERE omed.EndDT > GETDATE()
        AND (omed.DiscontinueDTS IS NULL OR omed.DiscontinueDTS > 
GETDATE())
        AND (
    (omed.OrderStatusDSC IS NULL) OR omed.OrderStatusDSC NOT IN 
('Canceled') )
        AND (GenericNM LIKE '%apixaban%'
        OR GenericNM LIKE '%Aspirin%'
        OR GenericNM LIKE '%Cilostazol%'
        OR GenericNM LIKE '%Clopidogrel%'
        OR GenericNM LIKE '%Dapigatran%'
        OR GenericNM LIKE '%Edoxaban%'
        OR GenericNM LIKE '%Prasugrel%'
        OR GenericNM LIKE '%Ticlopidine%'
        OR GenericNM LIKE '%Rivaroxaban%'
        OR GenericNM LIKE '%Warfarin%')
    GROUP BY omed.PatientEncounterID
       ,omed.StartDT
       ,omed.EndDT
      ,omed.DiscontinueDTS
      ,emed.EpicMedicationID
      ,emed.GenericProductID
      ,emed.MedicationNM
      ,emed.PharmaceuticalClassCD
      ,emed.PharmaceuticalClassDSC
      ,emed.PharmaceuticalSubclassCD
      ,emed.PharmaceuticalSubclassDSC
      ,emed.GrouperMedicationID
      ,CASE WHEN emed.ProductTypeID = 2 THEN 'OTC' ELSE 'Prescription' 
END
      ) meds on meds.patientEncounterID = pe.PatientEncounterID 
 WHERE hacpt.ProcedurePerformDT > '2023-05-01'
 AND pe.AppointmentStatusID = 2
 AND hacpt.CPT IN ('00731', '00732', '00740', '00810', '00811',
'00813', '0397T', '3130F', '43254', '43266', '43273', '44360', '44361',
'44370', '44383', '44384', '44397', '44402', '44403', '45347', '45349',
'45387', '45389', '45390', '47550', '47552', '47553', '47554', '76975',
'9124', 'C9779')
 AND prv.ProviderID IN ('30638', '35018', '08707', '08700', '29288', 
'08711', '32763', '33093', '28411', '28326')
```